# mod_rewrite hiding ".php" extension (No query strings)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to make

> domain.com/file.php

into

> domain.com/file

I've had a look at other questions but most are about hiding the filename and just displaying querystrings, I'm not going to be using querystrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure [none of these worked for you](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=removing+php+extension&submit=search)? A lot of those answers are pretty much what you want. Example, the very first result has these rules in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Alternatively, you can try turning on [Multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) and letting that handle it for you:

```
Options +Multiviews
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/file.php$ /file [L,R=301]
```